# Parsing terraform plan output to check for module vs resource block usage

Tags: json, azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, jq

I wanted to add a check to an existing terraform build and deployment pipeline to check that the configuration being written by devs is properly formatted and in line with company syntax

**Specifically I want to check to make sure they are not using plain resource blocks in thier config as opposed to module blocks**

For example I want to I want to make sure they are using

```
Module “eks_dev_wus2_app_cluster”
```

And not

```
Resource “aws_kubernetes_cluster” “eks_dev_wus2_App_cluster”
```

### Current approach

As I understand it I would need to first convert to json to parse through it

```
terraform show -no-color -json output.tfplan > output.json
```

Then I should use the jq tool to parse through the output per this article
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-parse-a-json-file-from-linux-command-line-using-jq

A little fuzzy on how I would go about specifically checking the blocks in the terraform config to confirm whether or not they are resource or module.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Is there a better way to get output values? Don’t need an entire solution, just looking to clarify some of the fogginess of approaching this problem

Comment: Have you seen [the documentation about that JSON plan output](https://www.terraform.io/internals/json-format)? I don't really want to say "just go read the documentation" but there's a lot of info in there so I expect it'll be easier to answer if you can be a bit more specific about what parts of that documentation you're unsure about, what you tried so far, etc.

Comment: Hey @MartinAtkins I feel like a bit of a fathead. I was perusing through the terraform output documentation and jq documentation but didn’t look at the json output one. Thanks. Ill chalk it up to code blindness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the output format, there is a list called `resource_changes`. Each change has an `address` field. To meet your requirement, each address should start with `module`. This makes the developer responsible only for the modules that they are changing with this terraform plan.

Assuming you already have output.json in place, you could do it like this:

```
LIST=$(cat output.json| jq -r ".resource_changes[].address")

for ADDRESS in $LIST
do
    if [[ $ADDRESS != "module."* ]]; then
        echo "$ADDRESS is outside of a module"
        exit 1
    fi
done
```

Comment: This is a little more heavyweight logic than I like to put in a bash script - if you don't have a deep bench of shell programmers, consider writing your check in a scripting language that other people on the team know well.

Comment: Appreciated Sir. Gave me a clearer understanding of how to leverage resource_changes and works perfectly. Will also keep in mind abstracting the logic to a more common language for my team. Cheers